# Google Sheet: Horizontal Consecutive Query Outputs

Tags: google-sheets, arraylist, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, transpose

I have a set of data that looks like the following:

| Faculty (A) | Course Name (B) | Course Description (C) | Units (D) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Doe | Math 101 | Intro to Math | 2 Units |
| John Doe | Math 102 | Intermediate Math | 3 Units |
| Jane Doe | Physics 101 | Intro to Physics | 4 Units |

I'm trying to create a query function that organizes the data on another sheet in the following way:

| Faculty (A) | Course Name 1(B) | Course Desc 1(C) | Unit Count 1(D) | Course Name 2(E) | Course Desc 2(F) | Unit Count 2(G) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Doe | Math 101 | Intro to Math | 2 Units | Math 102 | Intermediate Math | 3 Units |
| Jane Doe | Physics 101 | Intro to Physics | 4 Units |  |  |  |

Above is how I picture this theoretically. Here is an actual link to as sheet that shows a little closer to what I'm working with: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18ucJ7QQx39STKSm6EqH2yYkHd5AjZNlJxIwpQ9kGXdw/edit#gid=2020540687

Any help with this would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you say what the maximum number of course units per faculty would be?

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY(
 {A2:A, "×"&B2:B&"×"&C2:C&"×"&D2:D, B2:B&C2:C&D2:D}, 
 "select Col1,max(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col3"), 
 "offset 1", 0)),,9^9)), "×")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a challenge to get unstructured data to align correctly, but I think this may be the way to do it. It is a little complicated, but for each set of 'Course Name/Course Description/Units' it requires a `QUERY`. Please test it on a larger set of data. I came across issues relating to unsorted source data. For testing, I suggest you name the 'Units' the same as 'Faculty' so you can see if the 'Faculty' names line across correctly.

Relative to your 4 columns of source data (A:D), this goes in cell F1:

`=query(ARRAYFORMULA({countif(A1:A,A:A),COUNTIFS($A1:$A,$A1:$A,ROW($A1:$A),"<="&ROW($A1:$A)),$A:$D}),"select Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6 where Col2=1 order by Col1 desc,Col3,Col2 label Col3 'Faculty', Col4 'Course Name 1',Col5 'Course Description 1',Col6 'Units 1'",1)`

The other columns don't repeat 'Faculty' so the `QUERY` is slightly different. Notice `where Col2=2` changes... 3 for the 3rd set, 4 for the 4th set etc.

Also note that the data needs to be sorted by 'faculty with most courses' so that subsequent rows don't collapse.

In cell J1:

`=query(ARRAYFORMULA({countif(A1:A,A:A),COUNTIFS($A1:$A,$A1:$A,ROW($A1:$A),"<="&ROW($A1:$A)),$A:$D}),"select Col4,Col5,Col6 where Col2=2 order by Col1 desc,Col3,Col2 label Col4 'Course Name 2',Col5 'Course Description 2',Col6 'Units 2'",1)`

In cell M1:

`=query(ARRAYFORMULA({countif(A1:A,A:A),COUNTIFS($A1:$A,$A1:$A,ROW($A1:$A),"<="&ROW($A1:$A)),$A:$D}),"select Col4,Col5,Col6 where Col2=3 order by Col1 desc,Col3,Col2 label Col4 'Course Name 3',Col5 'Course Description 3',Col6 'Units 3'",1)`

In cell P1:

`=query(ARRAYFORMULA({countif(A1:A,A:A),COUNTIFS($A1:$A,$A1:$A,ROW($A1:$A),"<="&ROW($A1:$A)),$A:$D}),"select Col4,Col5,Col6 where Col2=4 order by Col1 desc,Col3,Col2 label Col4 'Course Name 4',Col5 'Course Description 4',Col6 'Units 4'",1)`

In cell S1:

`=query(ARRAYFORMULA({countif(A1:A,A:A),COUNTIFS($A1:$A,$A1:$A,ROW($A1:$A),"<="&ROW($A1:$A)),$A:$D}),"select Col4,Col5,Col6 where Col2=5 order by Col1 desc,Col3,Col2 label Col4 'Course Name 5',Col5 'Course Description 5',Col6 'Units 5'",1)`

Comment: Thanks for steps, this does look pretty complicated. I tried applying this to my sheet, but wasn't able to because it is a bit different. I realized I should have shared a sample sheet to start with. I'm very new at this, sorry. Her is a sample sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18ucJ7QQx39STKSm6EqH2yYkHd5AjZNlJxIwpQ9kGXdw/edit#gid=1071583782

Comment: player0 method works well. Adapted here:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY(
 {Data!D1:E,Data!S1:S, char(6655)&Data!H1:H&char(6655)&Data!I1:I&char(6655)&Data!J1:J&char(6655)&Data!K1:K&char(6655)&Data!L1:L&char(6655)&Data!Q1:Q, char(6655)&Data!H1:H&char(6655)&Data!I1:I&char(6655)&Data!J1:J&char(6655)&Data!K1:K&char(6655)&Data!L1:L&char(6655)&Data!Q1:Q}, 
 "select Col1,Col2,max(Col4) where Col1 is not null group by Col1,Col2 pivot Col5"), 
 "offset 1", 0)),,9^9)),char(6655)),""))`